# How to hide specific education in LinkedIn profile?

Tags: linkedin

Is there a way to hide specific school in LinkedIn profile?
I mean **hide** not completely *remove*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is currently not possible.

And knowing LinkedIn, I wouldn't expect it to be, either.

Answer (score 4):

To change the sections displayed on your public profile...

Move your cursor over Profile at the top of your homepage and select Edit Profile.

Click the URL link under your profile photo. It will be an address like www.linkedin.com/in/yourname.  This will open your public profile as it is currently seen on the site.

On the right side of the page, there is a section titled **Customize Your Public Profile**, click Make my public profile visible to everyone. Your basic information displays by default.

Check or uncheck the boxes to select which sections you'd like to display or hide. Education is one of the options you can check (show) or uncheck (hide).

The changes take effect immediately. You can reload that page to see any changes you made.

Comment: Thank you. This was helpful.